# C# NHibernate: How to do constructor injection into classmapping derived class?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am new with `NHibernate`. I somehow not able to find answer for my issue.
So let me ask here.

How can I dependency inject something into a class like this:

```
/*
  public abstract class ByCodeAutoClassMapping&lt;T&gt; : ClassMapping&lt;T&gt; where T : EntityBase ... etc
 */
using App.Data.Persistence.Infrastructure;
using App.Data.Persistence.Infrastructure.Builders;
using Domain;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;

namespace Persistence.Auto.Mappings
{
    public class EmployeeMapping : ByCodeAutoClassMapping&lt;Employee&gt;
    {
        protected override void InitCustomMappings(TableMapBuilder<Employee> tableMapping)
        {
            Schema("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to register persistence classes into some `IoC` container first and then provide these registration to `NHibernate` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to register the mapping classes by convention. Something like:

```
yourContainer.Register(AllTypes.DerivedFrom(typeof(ByCodeAutoClassMapping<>));
```

When you need to register the mapping types with NH, you should then be able to use your IoC container to resolve them:

```
nhMappingTypes = yourContainer.Resolve(typeof(ByCodeAutoMapping<>));
```

Comment: David hello and thank you for your answer. Actually I am registering my mapping classes like this: 
`var mapper = new ModelMapper(); mapper.AddMappings(typeof(EmployeeMappings).Assembly.GetTypes()); Configuration.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());`

For such a case I don't know how to make NHibernate use the registered types as you mentioned. It seems that NHibernate directly constructing mapping classes and throwing exception when the default public constructor of a mapping class is not present.

Answer (score 0):

I implement a new class derived of ModelMapper and change two implementations of two methods: 'AddMappings' and 'AddMapping' but with another names, in constructor of new type of ModelMappers receive the necesary parameters. Here my implementation, my necesary parameter in the ModelMappings is a object of ISesion type, but it can be whatever type you need:

```
public class FenixModelMapper : ModelMapper {
//Here
private readonly ISesion _sesion;


public FenixModelMapper(ISesion sesion)
{
  _sesion = sesion;
}

public void AgregarMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
  if (types == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
  }

  foreach (var type in types.Where(x =>
    typeof(IConformistHoldersProvider).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsGenericTypeDefinition))
  {
    AgregarMapping(type);
  }
}

private void AgregarMapping(Type type)
{
  object mappingInstance;
  try
  {
    //Here the code, create instante with Reflection passing my object
    mappingInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, _sesion);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new MappingException("Unable to instantiate mapping class (see InnerException): " + type, e);
  }

  var mapping = mappingInstance as IConformistHoldersProvider;
  if (mapping == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("type",
      "The mapping class must be an implementation of IConformistHoldersProvider.");
  }

  AddMapping(mapping);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've done this by using NHibernate [interceptors](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html), but maybe there are better approaches right now.